# How to update HttpEntity content?

Tags: servlets, httpentity

I have a HttpServletResponse. I'd like to get the content of its entity, change it and then send the response.

Getting the content and changing it is simple : `response.getEntity().getContent()`

But writing back the modifications into the entity, ... I don't see how I can do it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @yo_hahaDid you solve your issue?

Comment: nop. I thought I could get content from entity to get the server response ... But it's not the case. I'm stuck at how to get the XML (that is the reponse I want) from the httpServletResponse

Answer (score 1):

You can write with a below way, `responseFormat` can be `xml,json` or other format. Read the `responseOutput` as `byte` array and then create `header` then set content type, set content length and write to `httpEntity` byte array.

```
public HttpEntity<byte[]> writeResponse(String responseOutput, String responseFormat) {
        byte[] documentBody = null;
        try {
            documentBody = responseOutput.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", responseFormat));//response format can be "json"
        header.setContentLength(documentBody.length);
        return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(documentBody, header);
    }
```

***EDIT : *** org.springframework.http.HttpEntity is used.

Apache org.apache.http.HttpEntity [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.http.HttpEntity)

```
public String execute() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
  if (response == null) {
    HttpClient httpClient=HttpClientSingleton.getInstance();
    HttpResponse serverresponse=null;
    serverresponse=httpClient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity=serverresponse.getEntity();
    StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(entity.getContent(),writer);
    response=writer.toString();
  }
  return response;
}
```

[IOUtils.copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.Writer))

Comment: From which package did you use HttpEntity? The one in org.apache.http.HttpEntity is not generic.

Comment: IOUtils.copy doesn't take StringWriter as argument

Comment: @yo_hahaCheck your version, it should be org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils 2.4 I update my answer